# ModuleNotFoundError using CaseReader in OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

I'm trying to use a recorded case in OpenMDAO contained in "my_file.db"

when i execute the following code:

```
    import openmdao.api as om
    cr = om.CaseReader('my_file.db')
```

I get the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'groups'

'groups' is a folder from the openMDAO code that I used to record the case and now I'm trying to import it from a different directory. How can I redefine the path for om.CaseReader to look for the modules it needs?

Answer (score 1):

try setting your PYTHONPATH, as discussed here:

https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved using:

```py
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
import sys
sys.path.append( dirname )
```